# what is the problem in this butterworth filter

Tags: python, signal-processing

i am trying to remove the base wander noise from ecg signal, base wander noise is low-frequency artefact of around 0.5Hz , for that i tried a digital butterworth highpass filter:

code of filter

[image]

frequency response

[image]

the ecg signal used is the record 100 from mit bih arrhythmia data base ( record sampled at 360 samples per second), first i read the record using wfdb package and then i applied the filter on it, but the result looks something like this:

code of filtering the signal

[image]

the result

[image]

the result looks kinda off. i want to know where is the problem?

Comment: Please provide your code in a text format, rather than using [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your filter does not know the time step of your dataset, particularly in your call to [`bilinear`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.bilinear.html) where you explicitly give a sampling frequency of 1.

To demonstrate, let's start with a pretty strong signal:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 1_000
T = 4.
tau = 0.25 # period of signal, frequency of 4 Hz
f = 1 / tau # frequency
omega = 2 * np.pi * f # angular frequency

t, dt = np.linspace(0, T, N, endpoint = False, retstep = True)
fs = 1 / dt # sampling frequency in Hz

noise = np.random.random(N)
sig = np.sin(t * omega)
x = 0.2 * noise + sig

plt.plot(t, x)
plt.xlabel('time')
```

[image: signal_only]

Now let's start with the filter you've developed. My wave is higher frequency than your cutoff so it should be caught, but it isn't.

```
from scipy import signal
b, a = signal.butter(4, 0.5, 'high', analog = True, output = 'ba')
z, p = signal.bilinear(b, a, 1.)

x_filt = signal.lfilter(z, p, x)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, x)
plt.plot(t, x_filt)
plt.xlabel('time')
```

[image: signal_2]

Note that in your call to `bilinear` you are setting a sampling frequency of 1. Let's instead use our sampling frequency (defined above as `fs`).

```
z, p = signal.bilinear(b, a, fs)
x_filt = signal.lfilter(z, p, x)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, x)
plt.plot(t, x_filt)
plt.xlabel('time')
```

[image: time-step]

As a last note, you may sometimes observe a phase shift with Butterorth filters.
Again, I am not an expert and have only ever used them in cases where I was not worried about the phase, but [see here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17999/correct-for-shift-from-butterworth-filter) for suggestion on using a different type of filter if this is an issue. The [comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695367/most-efficient-way-to-filter-a-long-time-series-python) also suggest using a different filter for this reason.